# Can we configure Recycle bin in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can we configure Recycle bin in SharePoint online like can we change from 30 days to 60 days retention period.If yes where can i find the settings and is it available on all versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control retention period in SPO.